# LWUIT Button pressed and released

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-button

How to detect in LWUIT that button on form is pressed and hold, and how to detect that button is released.

Answer (score 0):

Yoo have in form and button in Lwuit functions that take care about thus actions.

keyPressed(int keyCode)- keyboard press

keyReleased(int keyCode) - keyboard released

pointerPressed(int x, int y) - touch press

ublic void pointerReleased(int x, int y) - touch released

Answer (score 0):

Button has pressed() and released() methods which you can override to detect long press. To detect short presses just use addActionListener() on the button.